# Stretching part of a xaml path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I am using Paths to build a custom content border for my app written in WPF. What I want is to have only the middle portion of the path stretched when the window is stretched (Figure 2) instead of the whole thing (Figure 3).

My first instinct was to split the path into three parts and put them in a Grid. The left and right paths would stay fixed while the middle path would stretch. The problem is, I can't figure out how to put a stroke around the whole thing without having it go in between the three paths as well.

**Note:** This image is a reference only, the actual border is more complex but still made up of three parts.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the three paths, or what the difference is between the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a grid with three borders?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Blue" Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="50" CornerRadius="10,0,0,10" BorderBrush="LimeGreen" BorderThickness="2,2,0,2"/>
    <Border Background="Red" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="LimeGreen" BorderThickness="0,2"/>
    <Border Background="Blue" Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="50" CornerRadius="0,10,10,00" BorderThickness="0,2,2,2" BorderBrush="LimeGreen"/>
</Grid>
```

Alternately you could wrap the grid in a border:

```
<Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" Background="Blue" BorderBrush="Red">
    <Grid Background="Green" Margin="20,0"/>
</Border>
```

Without knowing more about what's needed, it's hard to say which one is the right answer.  (If you're doing crazy stuff with clipping paths or interesting shapes, the first solution might be easier.)

Answer (score 1):

I would also use the Grid to allow the central part to stretch. Have you tried wrapping the Grid in a Border? As this should only create a border brush around the outside of the grid not in between the cells.

Answer (score 0):

The path syntax dictates if the stroke end point connects back to the start point.  If the path data ends with a "Z" then the end is connected to the start.

If you have a "Z" at the end of your path data for the left and right cells, then try removing the "Z".

see reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189041(v=vs.95).aspx#closecommand